# how to retrieve from firebase with equals

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve data from firebase. And I want to print data from `tglkeluar`. But I want to give the condition that the values from `tglkeluar` is equal to "12-03-2019". Then the status with the same date as "12-03-2019" will be printed.

I used the following code. But it doesn't print anything. 
How do I get data from firebase with compare it first?

```
 mDatabase2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Data data = postSnapshot.getValue(Data.class);

                String a= data.getTglkeluar();
                if(a.equals(getCurrentdate())){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "succes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
```

This is my database structure:

```
"data" : {
 "A01" : {
   "status" : 1,
   "tglkeluar" : "12-03-2019"
 },
 "A02" : {
   "status" : 1,
   "tglkeluar" : "10-03-2019"
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked what `getCurrentdate()` actually returns? My guess is that it actually not equal to what you have in your database. Also can you include how you initialized `mDatabase2`?

Comment: mDatabase2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("data");

Comment: i toast the return getCurrentDate and he is normal. and i try to upload the data from getCurrentdate(). its normal

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,here i am directly `comparing child value` with that `date` value and if data exist then `status is fetch` and you can used it ,for further processing.

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                                    DatabaseReference db=firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("data");//getting reference from data

         db.orderByChild("tglkeluar").equalTo(getCurrentdate())).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) 
                                            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

                                                Log.d("metch found","data is there");
                                               String value =dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();//getting value of status

                                               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "succes"+value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //printing that value in toast 
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }
                                });
```

Comment: after try. no data retrieve. and the toast do not appear

Comment: my mistake `equalTo(getCurrentdate())` here did you remove extra bracket `)` ? ,also try passing data manually pass like this -->`equalTo("12-03-2019")`

Comment: saved my day .thanks...

Comment: very thanks man..
but if i get current date with     public String getCurrentDate(){
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year, month, day;
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DATE);
        return day + "-" + (month+1) + "-   " + year;
    }

the result is "12-3-2019"
how to change to "12-03-2019"

Comment: here-> `"- " + year;` i saw little space there ,so your output after returning from that function might be like this `12-3- 2019`  which doesn't match with `12-03-2019` , so just remove that little space and try passing that function only in `equalTo(getCurrentdate())` it should work.